# Set start and end date for multiple DataFrames in Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have many DataFrames stored in a dictionary and I want to set start and end dates. I created two DataFrames `df1` and `df2` which are stored in a dictionary `dfs` and I try to set a start and end day for the DataFrames in the dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dates':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06'],
    'ID1':[0,0,1,2,1,-1], 
    'ID2':[1,0,0,2,4,-2]})
df1['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Dates'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dates':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05'],
    'ID1':[0,1,-1,1,4], 
    'ID2':[1,2,3,-1,2]})
df2['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Dates'])

dfs = dict()
dfs['df1'] = df1
dfs['df2'] = df2
```

The start and end dates are defined as follows:

```
start = pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')
end = pd.to_datetime('2021-01-04')
```

At the moment I only figured out how to define the start and end date separately for both DataFrames.

```
df1.loc[(df1['Dates'] >= start) & (df1['Dates'] <= end)]
```

Is there an efficient way to define it for many DataFrames in a dictionary without doing it for each individual DataFrame separately?

Many thanks!

Comment: Dict comprehension: `{k: d[d['Dates'].between(start, end)] for k,d in dfs.items()}`?

Comment: great thanks a lot! Is there also a way to define the start and end dates as dictionary and then use that as start and end?

Comment: Yes, say `starts={'df1':start1, 'df2':start2}` then `{k: d[d['Dates'].between(starts[k], end[k])] for k, d in dfs.items()}`

Comment: Hi @fjurt - you're asking a few questions in one here. See the guide to [ask]. There's nothing specific to [indexing and selecting data in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) which is different if the dataframes are in a dictionary. If you have questions about how to do dict comprehension or work with object held in dictionaries, ask that. If you have questions about pandas, ask that. It's up to you to figure out how to put the elements together into a full program :)

Comment: @Quang Hong thanks a lot!

Comment: @Michael Delgado sorry & thanks for pointing that out

Comment: No worries! Hopefully structuring your questions that way will be helpful in working through the programming puzzle as well :) Stack Overflow has its own set of rules that take a while to get a hang of but keep the questions coming!